# RecyclerView - how to scroll to the position of the required data item (by binded)?

Tags: xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I am new to android programming and I had a question, maybe I was just bad looking for an answer, but I wasted a couple of days on it.

I use RecyclerView for my data like

```
private JavaList<Good> goods = new JavaList<Good>();
public class Good : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public string name;
        public int quality;  //need
        public int real_quality;  // now
}
```

I have adapter, holder and etc., all of the documentation...
I receive barcodes from barcode scanner

```
public class MyScanReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
     public interface BarcodeDataInterface
        {
            void OnBarcodeReceived(string barcode);
        }

        private BarcodeDataInterface mBarcodeDataInterface;
        // some code
}
```

in the MainActivity.cs:

```
      public void OnBarcodeReceived(string barcode)
        {
            Good g = GetByBarcode(barcode);  // get good by barcode, 
            if (g == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Not found {barcode}.");
                return;
            }
            g.real_quantity++;  
            g.isChecked = g.real_quantity >= g.quantity; 

            recyclerView1.ScrollToPosition( ?? POSITION ?? );
            rvAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

and now
**I need to scroll to the position of founded good, but how do I get this position?**

Maybe I'm not doing everything right at all and there is some other way?
I look forward to any advice and suggestions! :)

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the postion of your good which receive from the barcode scanner in your RecycleView source.

For example:

```
private JavaList<Good> goods = new JavaList<Good>(); //this is the source of your recycleview
```

when you get the goods by barcode :

```
public void OnBarcodeReceived(string barcode)
    {
        Good g = GetByBarcode(barcode);  // get good by barcode, 
        if (g == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Not found {barcode}.");
            return;
        }
        g.real_quantity++;  
        g.isChecked = g.real_quantity >= g.quantity; 
        
        int position;
        for (int i = 0; i < goods.Count; i++)
        {
            if (goods[i].name.Equals(g.name))
            {
                position = i; //the position is what you want
            }
        }
        recyclerView1.ScrollToPosition(position);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I thought that the positions are not constant, but change depending on the re-use control's rows. Hm...

Comment: @Ten Will the data source of recycleview change? You just want to find the good in the list by barcode.So anyway, you're walking through the data source, and the position you get is where your good is in the list that's currently displayed.